# While finding green function, how to define deflection $u(x)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, greens-functions

In the PDE below, $u$ describes the deflection of a stiff beam with length density $\rho_l$, elastic modulus $E$, moment of inertia $I$ and external force density $f(x,t)$.

The question is to define the green function to the beams stationary deflection when $f(x,t) = f(x)$, that is, when the external force density is independent of time.

PDE: $$\rho_l u_{tt} - EIu_{xxxx} = f(x,t)$$
Boundary conditions: 
$$ u(0,t) = u_x(0,t) = u(l,t) = u_x(l,t) = 0$$

To my problem:
I got help from a teacher who told me that I should start by defining

$$u(x) = \int_0^l G(x,s)\frac{f(s)}{EI}ds$$

From here on, I have an idea of how to proceed. But I have no idea how he knew what to put as $u(x)$, and would love it if I could get an explanation of this. For example, how did he know that $f(s)$ should be divided by $EI$? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the beam is stationary, your PDE becomes
\begin{equation}
  -E I u_{xxxx} = f(x),
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
  -u_{xxxx} = \frac{f(x)}{EI}.
\end{equation}
So that's where that division comes from.

Now, looking at [the meaning of a Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_function#Definition_and_uses), let's *assume* that it satisfies your differential equation, with $\delta(x-s)$ in place of the source term.  In this case the source term is $\frac{f(x)}{EI}$, so we assume that
\begin{equation}
  -G_{xxxx} = \delta(x-s).
\end{equation}
(To get a solution for any particular problem, you'll usually need to find a particular Green's function satisfying your equation and the boundary conditions.  But for now, all we need is to just assume you already have one.)

Then, [the reason Green's functions are useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_function#Motivation) is that we can use a solution for $G$ to find $u$ by expressing the source term as an integral involving this $\delta$-function, and then replace $\delta$ with that Green's function quantity:
\begin{align}
  -\partial_x^4 u
  &=
  \frac{f(x)}{EI} \\
  &=
  \int \delta(x-s) \frac{f(s)}{EI} ds \\
  &=
  \int -\partial_x^4 G(x,s) \frac{f(s)}{EI} ds \\
  &=
  -\partial_x^4 \int G(x,s) \frac{f(s)}{EI} ds.
\end{align}
Now, comparing the first line with the last, we can see that one solution for $u$ is simply
\begin{equation}
  u(x) = \int G(x, s) \frac{f(s)}{EI} ds.
\end{equation}
Assuming $G$ also satisfies your boundary conditions, this is the solution you're looking for.

This is a very general idea, and is basically always what you do when using Green's functions.  You should just read that Wikipedia page I linked above to understand this idea more generally.  You will almost certainly use it again, but in slightly different forms, so you really will need to understand it on a more abstract level.

---

I'll note that you don't actually *have to* divide by $EI$.  You could have treated your source as just $f(x)$, so that the PDE was just
\begin{equation}
  -E I u_{xxxx} = f(x).
\end{equation}
Remember that you replace the source [here that's $f(x)$] by $\delta$, and then assume that $G$ satisfies that equation, so you would have to have
\begin{equation}
  -E I G_{xxxx} = \delta(x-s).
\end{equation}
The result would have been the same, except that the thing you call "the Green's function" would have been rescaled by $EI$.

You also could have divided by $-EI$, in which case
\begin{equation}
  u_{xxxx} = -\frac{f(x)}{EI}
\end{equation}
says that $-\frac{f(x)}{EI}$ is your source, so your Green's function would have to satisfy
\begin{equation}
  G_{xxxx} = \delta(x-s).
\end{equation}
It's all just a matter of when you divide by any given constant.

Comment: Thank you for an elaborate answer! It helped a lot. Right now I'm a bit confused about the $-G_{xxxx}=\delta(s-x)$. Does it matter in the $\delta$-function, if we write $\delta(s-x)$ or $\delta(x-s)$? Also, how do you realise that you should put a negative sign in front of $G_{xxxx}$, but not in the integral in front of $G(x,s)$?

Comment: The sign inside a $\delta$-function [doesn't really matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Scaling_and_symmetry), because it only "does anything" when $x-s = 0 = s-x$.  Now, as for the sign in front of $G_{xxxx}$, the idea is that $G$ should satisfy *exactly* the same equation as $u$ – except with the source replaced by a $\delta$-function.  In this case, the original PDE had a negative sign, so that's why it's in front of $G_{xxxx}$, but not inside the integral.  I've edited the answer to add a little more clarity; note the very last part for this particular issue.

Comment: I still have a few problems with understanding the Green-function on an abstract level, but this helped me a lot. I solved my problem, and I think I will get a better understanding by working with new problems a few days more. Thank you once again! I would give you a +1, but I don't have enough reputation lol.